# NoClassDefFoundExpetion: javax/persistence/PersistenceContext Spring ORM with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring.  I.m learning `spring` from [javapoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial). After learning some basics of spring from [javapoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial) and [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/), I moved towards learning `hibernate` with `spring`, but in very first try (example), I stucked with the expception: `NoClassDefFoundExpetion:   javax/persistence/PersistenceContext`. To resolve this exception, I've googled and looked for similar kind of situations (and their solutions) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850850/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-persistence-persistence) and [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/102195-noclassdeffounderror-javax-persistence-criteria-selection), but nothing helps me.
`Here` is the full `stacktrace:` of my exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceContext
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceContext
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<clinit>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 12 more
```

I'm using `eclipse-neon` IDE, `spring-framework 4.3.2 RELEASE`, `Hibernate-5.2.2 Final` and `Oracle 10G`(database).There is a STUDENT table in my database having 4-5 entries. Also I've written the`spring` code using simple (console base) `java project` and **NOT** using any build tool. `Here` is my complete code and libraries list which I'm currently using:

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

    private Integer rollNo;
    private String name;
    /**
     * @param rollNo
     * @param name
     */
    public Student(Integer rollNo, String name) {
        super();
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.name = name;
    }

//Getter and setter ....
```

**StudentDAO.java**

```
public class StudentDAO {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public StudentDAO(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;

    }

    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = template;
    }

    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        hibernateTemplate.save(student);
    }

    public List<Student> readAll() {
        return hibernateTemplate.loadAll(Student.class);
    }
}
```

I'm using java annotation based configuration, So my **AppConfig.java** is:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe", "user", "password");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean 
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean bean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        bean.setMappingResources("xml/student.hbm.xml");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        bean.setHibernateProperties(prop);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
        HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate((SessionFactory) sessionFactoryBean());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public StudentDAO DAO() {
        return new StudentDAO(hibernateTemplate());
    }

}
```

**Student.hbm.xml** XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
                <class name="bean.Student" table="student">
                                <rollNo name="rollNo">
                                                <generator class="assigned"></generator>
                                </rollNo>
                                <property name="name"></property>
                </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

and here is my **Main-Method Class**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
            StudentDAO dao = context.getBean(StudentDAO.class);
            List<Student> list = dao.readAll();
            for(Student s: list) 
                System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

here is the list of liberaries (with jar file) which I've included in my project:

**SPRING**

[image]

**HIBERNATE**

[image]

**Commons logging** and **ORALCE 10G Driver**
[image]

And some **other** too
[image]

How to solve the above mentioned exception, which `library` I've to add/remove or what else I can try to resolve the issue.
Regret for long question

**Example Reference**
This example is based on source code, available at [javapoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-and-spring-integration)

Comment: u need to add annotations for Student.java..... for eg:@Entity..

Comment: What else entity I need to add.

Comment: import  package called javax.persistence package and from that package u need to declare  above Class name..@Entity...

Comment: I've imported javax.persistence package and also declare Student.java as entity class using @Entity annotation, but still the problem continues

Comment: I'm already using hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar which has higher version then mentioned..

Comment: hibernate-jpa provides javax.persistence, I think you don't need javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar. Try removing it, because you have different implementations of the same class in some jars

Comment: @Tobías Thanks for suggestion, But I add javax.persistence later, when I was looking for solutions on net. I've tried it again, but all goes in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made slightly changes in my example. Instead of `AppConfig.java`, I used `ApplicationContext.xml`. Here is code for file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


                <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
                                <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
                                <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
                                <property name="username" value="sachin"></property>
                                <property name="password" value="sachin476"></property>
                </bean>

                <bean id="mysessionFactory"
                                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

                                <property name="mappingResources">
                                                <list>
                                                                <value>student.hbm.xml</value>
                                                </list>
                                </property>

                                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                                                <props>
                                                                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
                                                                </prop>
                                                                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                                                                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

                                                </props>
                                </property>
                </bean>

                <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
                                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
                </bean>

                <bean id="d" class="bean.dao.StudentDao">
                                <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
                </bean>
</beans>
```

and added two **more** `jar` files:

```
>commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar
>commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar
```

for `BasicDataSource` class.

Now It gives me `Exception:`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [xml/ApplicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/SessionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:63)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:725)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.isWritableProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    ... 11 more
```

But I peeped into `hibernate-core-5.2.2-Final.jar`, that had definition for `SessionFectory.class` in `org.hibernate` package i.e there was class entry named `org.hibernate.SessionFactory.class`. Now I'm wondering why it gives such exceptions

**UPDATE**
After lots of try and search on google, I found that `hibernate 5` doesn't support oracle10g drivers. so I've updated `ojdbc14.jar` to `ojdbc6.jar`, and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) Upgrade your `hibernate jpa-jar` since the `jpa` supported version for `hibernate4.3+` is **`2.1`**.

Comment: I'm already using hibernate-jpa-2.1-api 1.0.0 Final.jar. Which is latest update/version of hibernate-jpa api